# (Google chrome & Angular7) not showing typescript source code

Tags: google-chrome, angular7

Angular dev build (npm start). I am opening http://localhost:49152 in google chrome  dev tools i could not see the typescript source files.

Previously used to work. Stopped working from last week.

How to fix this. I want to see the typescript files in google chrome dev tools

Comment: You can add debugger to where need debug

Comment: Are you sure you have sourcemaps enables in your `tsconfig.json`?